# Help with hom0geneous function meets Euler's criterion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

a function $f: R^2 \rightarrow R$ is homogeneous of degree $\alpha$ for $\alpha > 0$ if $f(tx,ty) = t^\alpha f(x,y)$ for all $t>0, (x,y) ∈ R^2$

I have to show that a differentiable function that is homogenous of degree $\alpha$ meets Euler's Criterion

$\alpha f(x,y) = x \cdot \partial f/ \partial x (x,y) + y \cdot \partial f/ \partial y (x,y)$ for all $(x,y) ∈ R^2$

They gave me a hint to use the chainrule .

Comment: Is the 0 in "hom0geneous" symbolic?

Comment: @matt samuel typo actually hehe :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $u=tx$ and $v=ty$

So, $\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}=x$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}=y$. Now,

$$\dfrac{\mathrm df(u,v)}{\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}+\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}=$$

$=x\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}+y\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\tag 1$

Now, calculating it using the fact the function is homogeneous,

$$\dfrac{\mathrm df(u,v)}{\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{\mathrm df(tx,ty)}{\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{\mathrm d(t^\alpha f(x,y))}{\mathrm dt}=f(x,y)\dfrac{\mathrm d(t^\alpha)}{\mathrm dt}=$$

$=\alpha t^{\alpha-1}f(x,y)\tag 2$

The tricky part.

$\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}t\implies$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}$

and analogously for the partial wrt $y$

$\dfrac{1}{t}\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}$

We can substitute the expressions above in $(1)$ and considering it equals to $(2)$, we get,

$\alpha t^{\alpha-1}f(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{t}\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial x}+\dfrac{y}{t}\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial y}$

$\alpha t^{\alpha}f(x,y)=x\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial y}$

$\alpha f(tx,ty)=x\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial f(tx,ty)}{\partial y}$

The identity holds for any $t$, in particular for $t=1$ and we are done:

$\alpha f(x,y)=x\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$

Comment: You are welcome!